# Using psd_tools library to add color profile to a psd image that doesn't have it, from the official documentation of psd_tools,but still getting error

Tags: python, documentation, psd, color-profile

Using psd_tools library to add color profile to a psd image that doesn't have it, altering a bit the official documentation found here:
https://psd-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/psd_tools.html#psd_tools.PSDImage.image_resources
(under the property image_resources section) the code in question is this:

```
from psd_tools import PSDImage

psd = PSDImage.open('/home/kow_ml/Office_Work/Projects/CV/2D/PixelPIX/Data/Image/Input/final.psd')
image = psd.compose()

icc_profile = psd.image_resources.get_data(Resource.ICC_PROFILE)
image = psd.compose(apply_icc=False)
image.save('/home/kow_ml/Office_Work/Projects/CV/2D/PixelPIX/Data/Image/Input/final.psd', icc_profile=color_profile) 
#assigning "color_profile" to the psd image which contains a color profile value
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: compose() got an unexpected keyword argument 'apply_icc'
```

I don't know how to solve it as I am just trying to utilize official documentation code

I was expecting `color_profile` to be assigned as according to logic of the documentation but once I removed `image = psd.compose(apply_icc=False)` and replaced `image.save('/home/kow_ml/Office_Work/Projects/CV/2D/PixelPIX/Data/Image/Input/final.psd', icc_profile=color_profile)` with
`psd.save('/home/kow_ml/Office_Work/Projects/CV/2D/PixelPIX/Data/Image/Input/final.psd', icc_profile=color_profile)`
I got this new error:

```
TypeError: write() got an unexpected keyword argument 'icc_profile'.
```

As I am saying I am trying to use the official psd_tools documentation, but that itself is showing error, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.